# A for loop that remembers the previous i

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="p">Click the button to insert new cell(s) at the beginning of the first table row.</p>

<div id="console" style="border-style: dashed;">
length: <input type="text" id="length">
color: <input type="color" id="color">
<br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</div> 

<br>
    
<div id="resultArea" style="border-style: dashed;">
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
</div>
    <br>



<script>
//constant variables
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var cursor = 0;

function myFunction() {
var cursorInstant = cursor;
    for(var i=cursorInstant; i<(document.getElementById("length").value+cursorInstant); i++){

        
        
        
        x = Math.floor(i/12);
        y = i%12;
        document.getElementById("myTable").rows[x].cells[y].style.backgroundColor =  document.getElementById("color").value;
        cursor = i+1;
        
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So there is a Number that I input, and there is a for loop

What i want is this:When Number = 3, for loop loops from 0-2. Another Number input = 4, for loop loops from 3-6.Another another Number input = 10, for loop loops from 7-16.

My solution is that I have a constant (say A)
for loop statement will be something like

```
for(i=A; i< Number + A< i++){...}
```

And inside the loop, A will increment at some point.

but for some reason, my loop loops from A to 10times of (Number + A)
I don't understand

Comment: i can't understand please explain it

Comment: You have a *string*, not a number. It should be `+document.getElementById("length").value`.

Comment: I get it now.
document.getElementById("length").value gives me a string

Therefore document.getElementById("length").value gives me a string + 0 means to stick a 0 after the string: i.e. 2(string)+0 = 20

Resulting in 10times the Number

Comment: Gerardo Furtado Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=A; i< Number + A; i++)
{
   ...
}
A = A + Number
```

If you change the value of var Number inside the loop, the factor (Number + A ) increases each time, Sometime it may be endless

Comment: I know, thats why in my code, I increment the variable A at the end of the loop, and before I start the loop, I make another variable A-Instant = A, which only reads once before I start the loop, and use that A-Instant in the for statment

Comment: But thakns a lot anyways :D